# Returning an Array Manipulates Original Value in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, arguments

This is my first question on the site and I am sure I'll find my answer here.

For school, I was trying to do some basic C# coding for a challenge that was given to us.

Here is the problem:

Normally when I pass a value through a method I don't run into issues. Like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Declare Integer
    int originalInt = 20;

    // Call the Method
    int multipliedInt = Multiplication(originalInt);

    // Prompt
    Console.WriteLine("Original: {0} Modified: {1}", originalInt, multipliedInt);
}

// Method
static public int Multiplication(int original) 
{
    // Quik Maffs
    int modifiedValue = original * 2;

    return modifiedValue;
}
```

The above example works just fine. The original value is 20 and the modified value is 40.

However, this changes when I attempt to do that with an array:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Declare Original Array
    int[] originalArray = new int[] {1, 4, 6, 8, 12};

    // Call Method
    int[] multipliedArray = Multiplication(originalArray);

    // Prompt
    Console.WriteLine("Original: [{0}], Multiplied: [{1}]", String.Join(", ", originalArray), String.Join(", ", multipliedArray));
}

// Method
static public int[] Multiplication(int[] original) 
{
    // New Int
    int[] modified = original;

    // Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < modified.Length; i++) 
    {
        modified[i] *= 2;
    }

    return modified;
}
```

The code above returned the modified value twice. It seems like it modifies the original value as well.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Arrays are passed by reference, so you're passing a reference to your original array, and not a copy of it's value as you're expecting.

Comment: The difference is that in the first example, you're passing the variable by value. In the second example, you're passing a reference to the array. When you use the int argument, the method receives a copy of the value. With the array, you're passing a reference to the array instead of a copy of it.

Comment: @JonathonChase  Ah, I didn't know this. So I'm assuming what I'd have to do is create a new int array within the method.

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong, some people here including @Eser can be elitist. As a previous user mentioned, arrays are passed by reference. You can make your function void and remove your return statement and everything will be good to go. Edit: not quite, you'll need to change which array you're referencing within the function.

Comment: Yes. You'd have to create a new array in the method.

Comment: @itsme86 As bad as it is, I didn't know that arrays passed as a reference. I thought it was treated as other datatypes like my first example. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: No problem. There are other types that are passed by value as well. Basically, anything that's a struct (believe it or not, int, double, float, decimal, etc.) is passed by value (a copy is created), and anything that's a class is passed by reference.

Comment: You may find these documents helpful: [Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) & [Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)

Comment: @emsimpson92 Thanks for this. You mentioned removing the return statement and making the function void: would this require me pass the array through a loop in main and have each index go through the function? Hopefully I worded that correctly. Still trying to get into the lingo.

Comment: No, you can just run a loop within your function to modify the various indexes of your original array.

Comment: @itsme86 That is actually very useful to know. I'll definitely write that into my notes!

Comment: @emsimpson92 That would still entail modifying the original array. I think OP wants a copy of the array that has the original values and a copy with the new values.

Comment: It would probably be easier to make your array a list and just run a `foreach` loop rather than have a separate function that does this.

Comment: In that case, OP can just pass multipliedarray and modify those values.

Comment: @mjwills I'm sorry, I didn't know the difference between them and wouldn't have known if this was a duplicate question.

Comment: If, instead of `int[] modified = original;` you did `int[] modified = original.ToArray();` that would instantiate a new array, and you'll be able to keep the original values unchanged.

Comment: There is no need to apologise. Have a read of the duplicate and hopefully it will be of value of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is a *value type*. When you pass a value type to a method, you pass a copy of the value.

Arrays are *reference types*. When you pass a reference type to a method, you pass a copy of the reference... but both the copy and original still refer to the *same* object.

Now it seems you may have understood this much, because of this code:
*(This is why I re-opened the question... the stock ref-vs-value answer wasn't gonna cut it here)*

```
int[] modified = original;
```

However, the other thing that happens with reference types is assignments also only copy the reference. So `modified` and `original` in that snippet again refer to the *same* array object.

To fix this, you need to make an actual deep copy of the array. There are several ways to do this. I would tend to write the method this way:

```
static public IEnumerable<int> Multiplication(IEnumerable<int> original) 
{
    return original.Select(i => i * 2);
}
```

...and append a `.ToArray()` at the end of the method call if and only if I really need a full array (hint: very often it turns out you don't), like this:

```
int[] multipliedArray = Multiplication(originalArray).ToArray();
```

or like this:

```
var multipliedArray = Multiplication(originalArray);
```

But I understand there are a number of things here that aren't very familiar to a beginner. You might try something more like this:

```
static public int[] Multiplication(int[] original) 
{
    int[] modifed = new int[original.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
    {
        modified[i] = original[i] * 2;
    }

    return modified;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for taking the time out of your day to write this answer. Very much appreciated! I also tried your solution and it helped me tremendously. Not only within the code, but in my understanding of the topic.